# Android development using Android Studio or Xamarin using Visual Studio

Tags: android, java, c#

I'm at a bit of a cross roads. I'm a seasoned C# developer. I want to create a software application that uses the Android platform. I need to know given some criteria which is better for developing the software for Android.

I know C#. I don't know Java but I'm more than prepared to learn it.
Which platform (C# - using Xamarin) or Java would make my development route easier.
Among the techs I need to use includes location, maps, access web services, store data locally (on the phone).
I also need to know if there are any easy ORMS to use in each language, gui generators (e.g. automatically generate views from a class).

Given my criteria and YOUR personal experience using BOTH techs (C#, Java) to create android software can you recommend to me which route I should take.  Please be as thorough as possible in your reasoning.

Comment: "I want to create a software application that leverages the Android platform": Are you writing this app specifically for Android? Or is Android just one of the targets? This could be a great question but please reformulate before it gets closed based on http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-tool-x-versus-tool-y-a-fair-question

Comment: Leverages.. i.e. uses Android. Not anything else